# How to print different items depending on a random print in Python?

Tags: python, random, sample

How to print different items depending on a random print in Python? Here is part of my script.

```
Mage = "Mage"
Warrior = "Warrior"
Thief = "Thief"

skilltree = (Mage, Warrior, Thief)

print random.choice (skilltree)
```

Now say it randomly chose Warrior. In my next script it would print 7 skills. But if it were to randomly choose Thief or Mage they would of been 7 completely different skills. So I want the 7 skills you get to depend on the randomly chosen skill tree.

Answer (score 2):

You have done the hard part. Now you just need to map the skills to each category. For instance, using a dictionary:

```
skills = {'Mage': range(7), 'Warrior': range(7,14), 'Thief': range(14,21)}
choice = random.choice(skilltree)
print skills[choice]
```

This will print the list of skills you associated with the chosen skilltree. I used `range` just to illustrate, you could have a list of strings with the skills.

Answer (score 1):

I will just illustrate a little bit further with Paulo's example in case you are not familiar with using a dictionary (and like he said using a dictionary is probably the best choice for a mapping).

```
MageSkills = ["Mskill1", "Mskill2"]
ThiefSkills = ["Tskill1", "Tskill2"]
WarriorSkills = ["Wskill1", "Wskill2"]
skills = {'Warrior': WarriorSkills, 'Mage': MageSkills, 'Thief': ThiefSkills}

choice = 'Warrior'

print(skills[choice])
```

Answer (score 0):

The general concept of a solution has been outlined by others, but I think they're missing the key misunderstanding behind your question, which is how to persist something that you randomly chose and printed. As far as that goes, and for understanding this is what I would do:

```
import random

classes = ("Mage", "Warrior", "Thief")
skill_dictionary = {"Mage": ["Fireball", "Ice Blast"...], "Warrior": [...]} # etc
random_class = random.choice(classes) # Keep a version around for yourself
print random_class # print the version you just saved so you still have a copy
print skill_dictionary[random_class] #Then use the saved version to get the skill list
```

An important thought distinction to have here is separating getting the data from displaying it. First you randomly choose the data, and only after you already have it do you decide to show it to the user with your print statement.

The dictionary is just a key/value store (something that maps keys(your classes) to values (your skills)). It happens to fit this problem well, but you could implement this in other ways.

Comment: I thought the real problem was the mapping of skills to the choice, but I edited my answer to show where the `choice` variable comes from, in case you are right.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida an entirely reasonable assumption. Only time will tell which one of us was right.